# jquery selector, how to not select certain class inside selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have selector like follow:

```
$('#codes-datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {});
```

And I would like not to have buttons triggering this selector.
For example. I have inside the table a button:

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

I've tried already many combination with `.not('.btn')` and `:not(.btn)` but none worked out.

Please help.

Comment: "btn" is a class, try with `.btn`

Comment: Tried, this is spelling error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prevent this is to have one more statement after the event binding takes place on `tr`s.

This statement will prevent propagation of event, and will target `.btn`s only:

```js
$('#codes-datatable tbody tr').on('click', function() {
  alert('hello');
});

$('#codes-datatable tbody .btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="codes-datatable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td><button class="btn">Button</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks counter productive

Answer (score 1):

Using event delegation you still have the opportunity to test the `event.target` property to process events depending on the actual clicked element.

```js
// Listen to event on <div> when coming from a <p> element
$('div').on('click', 'p', function (e) {
   // Only log if the actual target hasn't a "btn" class.
   // Put whatever selector matches elements to filter
   if (!$(e.target).is('.btn')) {
      console.log(
         "Something that doesn't have the 'btn' class set has been clicked!"
      );
   }
   // Process event …
});
```

```css
br{display: inline-block; margin: 20px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    »Hasn't btn class«
    <br>
    <span class="btn">»Has btn class«</span>
  </p>
</div>
```